# error Compile shared libraries with -fPIC

Tags: shared-libraries, cross-compiling, snmpd

While I run snmpd daemon on powerpc board(a.p.) I am getting this error:

```
R_PPC_REL24: Compile shared libraries with -fPIC!
/usr/local/sbin/snmpd: symbol 'strlen': can't handle reloc type 0xa in lib
/lib/libnetsnmpmibs.so.15'
sh: you need to specify whom to kill
```

I googled and found that the `-fPIC` flag should be there while compiling and its place should be right after gcc, so I changed my Makefie accordingly. Here is a snippet of my makefile:

```
$(Q)cd $(PROJECT_BUILD_DIR)/$(NET_SNMP_PKG) && ./configure --target=$(TARGET_TRIPLET) \  
        --host=$(HOST_TRIPLET) \
        --build=$(BUILD_TRIPLET) \   
        --with-cc="$(CR_COMPLR)gcc -fPIC" \`  
        --with-cflags="-Os -I$(RFS)/lib -I$(NMS_DIR)/include" \`  
        --with-linkcc="$(CR_COMPLR)gcc -fPIC" \`
```

As you can see I embedded `-fPIC` right after gcc, but I am still getting an error. I have cross compiled for powerpc platform and I am using latest buildroot-2011.11 and gcc 4.3.6 and uClibc version 0.9.32. What may be the cause of error?

P.S. When I do  `nm libnetsnmpmibs.so.15 | grep strlen` then I get output as `U strlen`. Does this mean it is undefined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the problem. actually the main thing is to compile with `-fPIC` only.

In my case I was compiling `snmp` libraries with `-fPIC` correctly but some of the functions were dependent on libraries of other packages (`nms`). As I am working on firmware development there are more than 20 packages involved. So I compiled `nms` libraries with `-fPIC` and error is resolved.